# C# Rellenar formulario tras una búsqueda en dos tablas relacionadas

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, formularios, datatable

Buenas tardes. Llevo ya un tiempo intentando resolver este problema y no lo consigo solucionar, (me explico, puede ser un poco largo.)

Estoy haciendo un formulario que muestra registros de una tabla (componentes) y a esto añade los registro de una segunda tabla (proveedores). Ambas están relacionadas para que el formulario, que esta rellenándose a partir de la tabla componentes pueda rellenar los campos de proveedores. Es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el formulario se muestran:

1. Listbox con nombres de componentes, al hacer clic en un nombre se
   cargan los datos completos al resto del formulario.
2. Textbox para los campos de la tabla componentes, para este ejemplo
   nombre_componente.
3. Textbox para los campos de la tabla proveedores que debería
   rellenarse automáticamente ya que esta relacionada con componentes.
   Para este ejemplo_nombre proveedores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo bien, funciona como debiera.

El problema viene al hacer una búsqueda sobre los datos y mostrar el resultado sobre estos mismos controles. Hacerlo sobre una tabla sencilla funciona perfectamente, simplemente volcando el resultado de una QUERY a una instancia datatable y luego cambiando el Datasource a esa instancia. Eso funciona.

Sin embargo en el caso de querer cargar datos relacionados de otra tabla eso ya no funciona por que las instancias de DataTables no tienen las relaciones del DataSet original. Se crea una sola tabla con ambos resultados:

```
            else
        {
            // Búsqueda general cuando no se cumplen las anteriores condiciones
            OdbcDataAdapter sdata = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT componentes.*,nombre_empresa FROM proveedores INNER JOIN componentes ON proveedores.id = id_prov_comp WHERE nombre_empresa ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%' OR nombre_componente ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%' OR referencia ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%' OR peso_uni ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%' OR codigo_barras ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%' OR fecha_ult_precio ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%'", conn);

            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();

            sdata.Fill(dtbl);


            componentesBindingSource.DataSource = dtbl;


        }

        //resetea el campo de busqueda y lo deja listo para la proxima busqueda.

        textBox_comp_consulta_buscar.Text = null;
```

Y al intentar rellenar los datos del formulario el campo proveedor pierde su relación y no cambia al seleccionar otro componente, ya que los datos se están tomando de una nueva tabla instancia conjunta(INNER JOIN) y no de las tablas relacionadas originales.

Como no pude arreglar esto, pensé en crear un instancia .Clone() del DataSet y trabajar sobre eso, pero no puedo crearla dentro de la declaración if/else.

Así que ahora mismo estoy creando las instancias del DataSet, las DataTables, sus Claves Primarias y sus relaciones directamente dentro de la declaración ELSE. Ahora mismo el código es este:

```
            else
        {
            // Busqueda general cuando no se cumplen las anteriores condiciones

            //OdbcDataAdapter sdata = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT componentes.*,proveedores.id,nombre_empresa FROM proveedores INNER JOIN componentes ON proveedores.id = id_prov_comp WHERE nombre_empresa ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%' OR nombre_componente ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%' OR referencia ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%' OR peso_uni ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%' OR codigo_barras ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%' OR fecha_ult_precio ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%'", conn);
            OdbcDataAdapter sdata = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM componentes WHERE nombre_componente ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%'", conn);
            OdbcDataAdapter sdata2 = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE nombre_empresa ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%'", conn);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable("dtbl");
            DataTable dtbl2 = new DataTable("dtbl2");

                sdata.Fill(dtbl);
                sdata2.Fill(dtbl2);

                ds.Tables.Add(dtbl);
                ds.Tables.Add(dtbl2);

            dtbl.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtbl.Columns["id"] };
            dtbl2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtbl2.Columns["id"] };

            DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("provcomp",
                ds.Tables["dtbl2"].Columns["id"],
                ds.Tables["dtbl"].Columns["id_prov_comp"]);

            ds.Relations.Add(dr);
            ds.AcceptChanges();

            proveedoresBindingSource1.DataSource = dtbl2;
            componentesBindingSource.DataSource = dtbl;
        }
```

De este codigo obtengo dos comportamientos:

1. El primero si la búsqueda son términos que están presentes en la
   tabla componentes (dtbl), de la linea *ds.Relations.Add(dr);*
   obtendré el error: **"No se puede habilitar esta restricción ya que
   todos los valores no tienen los valores primarios
   correspondientes."**
2. Sin embargo si la búsqueda es un termino presente en la tabla
   proveedores (dtbl2), no hay error, y el formulario carga en vacio,
   excepto el campo proveedor.

Bueno pues aquí estoy atascado, como puedo conseguir lo que intento, ¿eh echo algo mal? ¿o algún otro método?, llevo días dando vueltas por Internet sin éxito.

Answer (score 0):

> El problema viene al hacer una búsqueda sobre los datos y mostrar el resultado sobre estos mismos controles. Hacerlo sobre una tabla sencilla funciona perfectamente, simplemente volcando el resultado de una QUERY a una instancia datatable y luego cambiando el Datasource a esa instancia. Eso funciona.

En lugar de usar ese método, te propngo el uso de la clase [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx), mediante su propiedad `RowFilter`.

El siguiente ejemplo consta de:

- 2 `DataGridViews`, uno para la tabla principal y otro para la
  secundaria.
- 1 `TextBox` para introducir el ***id*** del proveedor a
  buscar.
- 1 `Button` para iniciar la búsqueda.

  ```
  Public Class Form1

      Dim MiDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
      Dim dvDetalles As DataView

      Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
          ' Valores experimentales para la tabla primaria '
          Dim dtPrimaria_Proveedores As DataTable = New DataTable("Proveedores")
          With dtPrimaria_Proveedores.Columns
              .Add("id")
              .Add("nombre_empresa")
              .Add("cif_nif")
          End With
          With dtPrimaria_Proveedores.Rows
              .Add("1", "Electrónica Jujuy", "1234567890")
              .Add("2", "Helados Misiones", "2345678901")
              .Add("3", "Sistemas Neuquén", "3456789012")
              .Add("4", "Gaseosas Entre Ríos", "4567890123")
          End With

          ' Valores experimentales para la tabla secundaria '
          Dim dtSecundaria_Componentes As DataTable = New DataTable("Componentes")
          With dtSecundaria_Componentes.Columns
              .Add("id")
              .Add("nombre_componente")
              .Add("referencia")
              .Add("id_proveedor")
          End With
          With dtSecundaria_Componentes.Rows
              .Add("1", "Resistencia 1k", "1E1", "1")
              .Add("2", "Cucurucho", "2H2", "2")
              .Add("3", "Compresor de video", "3S3", "3")
              .Add("4", "Lima limón 1L", "4G4", "4")
              .Add("5", "Frutas rojas", "5H5", "2")
              .Add("6", "Editor Binario", "4S4", "3")
              .Add("7", "Guayaba Mango 3L", "1G1", "4")
              .Add("8", "Diseñador UML", "2S2", "3")
          End With

          ' Agrega las tablas al DataSet '
          MiDataSet.Tables.Add(dtPrimaria_Proveedores)
          MiDataSet.Tables.Add(dtSecundaria_Componentes)

          ' Crea la relación '
          MiDataSet.Relations.Add("proveedores_componentes", _
          MiDataSet.Tables("Proveedores").Columns("id"), _
          MiDataSet.Tables("Componentes").Columns("id_proveedor"))

          ' Establece los enlazadores '
          Dim PrimariaBindingSource As New BindingSource
          Dim SecundariaBindingSource As New BindingSource

          PrimariaBindingSource.DataMember = "Proveedores"
          PrimariaBindingSource.DataSource = MiDataSet

          SecundariaBindingSource.DataMember = "proveedores_componentes"
          SecundariaBindingSource.DataSource = PrimariaBindingSource

          ' Asigna el origen de datos para los DataGridViews '
          Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = PrimariaBindingSource
          Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = SecundariaBindingSource

          ' Pide una vista de la tabla secundaria para realizar las búsquedas '
          dvDetalles = MiDataSet.Tables("Componentes").DefaultView
      End Sub

      Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
          ' La propiedad RowFilter permite filtrar las filas '
          dvDetalles.RowFilter = "id_proveedor=" & Me.TextBox1.Text

          ' El resultado del filtro se muestra en el DataGridView2 '
          Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = dvDetalles
      End Sub
  End Class
  ```

Enlaces útiles:

- [DataViews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/fdcwwhez(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Administrar DataViews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/4xz507ds(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ChildViews y Relaciones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/fa04ha86(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

### 2ª EDICIÓN

Otra forma para filtrar es usando la propiedad `Filter` del `BindingSource`.

En el siguiente ejemplo las tablas son las mismas que las del código anterior, con las mismas filas. Usé *Access*, porque no tengo *PostgreSQL*.

Los controles son un `ListBox` que lista los nombres de los componentes, un `TextBox` para cada campo, y un `TextBox` para buscar.

La búsqueda se realiza a medida que el usuario va ingresando el texto.
La actualización de los controles es automática.

```
        private DataSet ds = new DataSet("BD");
        private BindingSource bs_ProveedoresComponentes;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da_Componentes = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT c.id as id_componente, nombre_componente, referencia, id_proveedor, nombre_empresa, cif_nif FROM Componentes c INNER JOIN Proveedores p ON c.id_proveedor = p.id", cn);

        // Se llena ds con el INNER JOIN entre las tablas Proveedores-Componentes.
        da_Componentes.Fill(ds, "Proveedores-Componentes");

        // Se crea el enlace para la tabla INNER JOIN.
        bs_ProveedoresComponentes = new BindingSource(ds, "Proveedores-Componentes");

        // Se enlazan todos los controles.
        this.ListBox1.DataSource = bs_ProveedoresComponentes;
        this.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "nombre_componente";

        this.txt_componente_id.               DataBindings.Add("Text", bs_ProveedoresComponentes, "id_componente");
        this.txt_componente_nombre_componente.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs_ProveedoresComponentes, "nombre_componente");
        this.txt_componente_referencia.       DataBindings.Add("Text", bs_ProveedoresComponentes, "referencia");
        this.txt_componente_id_proveedor.     DataBindings.Add("Text", bs_ProveedoresComponentes, "id_proveedor");

        this.txt_proveedor_id.            DataBindings.Add("Text", bs_ProveedoresComponentes, "id_proveedor");
        this.txt_proveedor_nombre_empresa.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs_ProveedoresComponentes, "nombre_empresa");
        this.txt_proveedor_cif_nif.       DataBindings.Add("Text", bs_ProveedoresComponentes, "cif_nif");       
    }

    private void txtBuscar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string buscar = this.txtBuscar.Text.Trim();
        bs_ProveedoresComponentes.Filter = "nombre_empresa LIKE '%" + buscar + "%'";
    }
```

**Otra opción:**
para usar las tablas individuales, sin el `INNER JOIN`, se puede usar `WHERE`, pero se necesitará el parámetro del `id`:

```
SELECT * FROM Proveedores WHERE id = paramid
```

Y eso requerirá que se codifique el evento `ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged`, para actualizar los datos del proveedor.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, usar un Dataview introduce el mismo problema, internamente se esta creando una "instancia" del dataset por lo que la estructura de este se pierde, perdiendo las relaciones, en definitiva no funciona. Ademas no quiero usar datagridviews. Buscare otra solucion.

Comment: Ya publiqué otro ejemplo, usando `BindingSource` en lugar de las clases que no quieres usar, fijate si te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

espero no sea muy tarde aún, pero esta sería mi forma de realizar lo que solicitas.

Primero Cargar los datos desde la BD

```
void CargarDatos()
    {
        //................
        //...............
        OdbcDataAdapter sdata = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT componentes.*,nombre_empresa FROM proveedores INNER JOIN componentes ON proveedores.id = id_prov_comp", conn);

        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();

        sdata.Fill(dtbl);

        componentesBindingSource.DataSource = dtbl;
        dgvData.DataSource = componentesBindingSource;
        //................
        //...............
    }
```

Luego agregar a cada textbox la visualización de una propiedad del origen de datos el siguiente método

```
void AddBinding()
    {
        try
        {
            //Desasociar Binding
            txtId.DataBindings.Clear();
            txtNombre.DataBindings.Clear();
            txtReferencia.DataBindings.Clear();
            txtProveedor.DataBindings.Clear();

            //ASociar binding
            txtId.DataBindings.Add("TEXT", componentesBindingSource, "Id");
            txtNombre.DataBindings.Add("TEXT", componentesBindingSource, "nombre_componente");
            txtReferencia.DataBindings.Add("TEXT", componentesBindingSource, "referencia");
            txtProveedor.DataBindings.Add("TEXT", componentesBindingSource, "nombre_empresa");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "AddBinding...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        
    }
```

Este método es el que realiza el filtrado:

```
void Filtrar()
    {
        try
        {
            if (componentesBindingSource.DataSource != null)
            {
                componentesBindingSource.Filter = $" nombre_componente LIKE '%{txtBuscarPorNombre.Text}%' or referencia  LIKE '%{TxtBuscarPorReferencia.Text}%'";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Filtrando...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

La forma de filtrar sería:

```
private void TxtBuscarPorReferencia_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Filtrar();
    }
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.